# android google.api.gms.location and serviceIntent memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

For my Android application I had implemented a LocationService - basically a IntentService which calls the google.api.gms.location API.

Then I've noticed that the application memory usage started to increase constantly which basically meant that the application had one or more memory leaks.

I've used heap dumps and the Eclipse Memory Analyzer tool to investigate the problem and I found the following "suspects".

[image]

**Issue 1**: LocationRequest was allocated in onLocationChanged() and never deallocated:

```
LocationRequest location_request = new LocationRequest();
```

And the solution was to declare location_request as static:

```
private static LocationRequest location_request = null;
```

**Issue 2**: google_api_client() was checked each time the location request was changed.

```
if (google_api_client.isConnected()) { ... }
```

And the solution was remove this function call (!?).

Now these memory leaks were fixed but I would really like to understand the underlying causes for them. Basically the questions is: **Are there some special rules for allocating objects inside IntentServices?**

Thank you.

Comment: It is not related to IntentService. As you were creating location req object in onLocationChanged() which is called frequently so the heap was growing. You do not need to re-create the loc req object again and again. You can re-use the same if you want to change the loc configuration.

Comment: I want to dynamically change the location service update interval therefore I need to call requestLocationUpdates() with a different LocationRequest. If I allocate a new LocationRequest each time I change the update interval then I'm sure that the location_request members have the correct default values ... however this is not true for static declaration of location_request. Therefore I would say that static declaration is not the correct solution. Instead I let the dynamic allocation and I've put `location_request = null` at the end of onLocationChanged() function. This seems to work.

Comment: Just tested the above: `location_request = null;` at the end doesn't work however `private static LocationRequest location_request = null;` works. I understand this solution but I still don't know why the memory leak happened in the first case. Perhaps `FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()` keeps an internal reference to the passed parameter?

Comment: I mean the private variable for location req object. That is fine, It will work. May be framework has reference to it. Better you call removeUpdates() as well to clean up to make sure things are cleaned. Againc reate loc req and startReqUpdates().

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think this is a **false alarm**. After several `System.gc()` call the actual memory is constant therefore I would say that increasing memory != memory leak. I'm sorry for this but it was really confusing.